# How to bind kendo-menu to remote datasource?

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, bind, kendo-menu

below is my code

```
$("#lhsPanelBar").kendoMenu({
    orientation: 'vertical',
    dataSource:
        {
            type: 'json',
            transport:  {
                    read: "http://localhost:3549/api/LHSMenu"
                }
        },
});
```

but there is not server hit on controller and menu is displayed as "undefined".

Controller code

```
public class LHSMenuController : ApiController
{
    private IRepo repo;
    public LHSMenuController()
    {
        repo = new Repository();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<LHSMenu> GetLHSMenu()
    {
        return this.repo.Menu;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code from the controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kendo UI Menu doesn't support binding to a remote data source for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

The kendo menu cannot do it directly but you can use the change method of a data source and create the menu from this function, try this:

```
var menuDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                      transport: {
                            read: {
                              url: "/app/test/menuItems",
                              dataType: "json"
                            }
                          },
                        change: function() {
                            var dataMenu = this.data(); 
                            console.log("from change: " + dataMenu.length);
                            for (var indexMenuDataSource = 0; indexMenuDataSource < dataMenu.length; indexMenuDataSource++) {
                                var objectToPut = {};
                                var data = dataMenu[indexMenuDataSource];
                                objectToPut.text = data.text;
                                objectToPut.url = data.url;
                                objectToPut.cssClass = data.cssClass;
                                objectToPut.imageUrl = data.imageUrl;
                                if(data.items.length > 0){
                                    objectToPut.items = [];
                                    for(var indexSubItem = 0; indexSubItem < data.items.length; indexSubItem++){
                                        var subItem = {};
                                        subItem.text = data.text;
                                        subItem.url = data.url;
                                        subItem.cssClass = data.cssClass;
                                        subItem.imageUrl = data.imageUrl;
                                        objectToPut.items.push(subItem);                                            
                                    }
                                }
                                menu.insertAfter(objectToPut,  menu.element.children("li:last"));
                            }
                        }
            });

            var menu = $("#menuTest").kendoMenu().data("kendoMenu");
            menuDataSource.read(); //Will launch the change function
```

Note:  It is a draft, create another function to iterate over sub > sub > sub items.

Comment: Great answer, do you have error handling in case say the menu returns zero items?  I'm trying to hack my way through that and not being very successful.

Answer (score 0):

You should return your result in a json friendly format for the Menu. Try this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<LHSMenu> GetLHSMenu()
{
    return Json(this.repo.Menu,JsonBehavoir.AllowGet);
}
```